# What will I do using the LZMA?

Tags: delphi

Hello I download Lzma for delphi its 48 kb.What will I do now?How can I use it?
Is there any example code for Lzma in DElphi?

Comment: What is [LZMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZMA) ? My crystal ball which is using Google (like me) told me you are talking about [7z format](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html) do you :) ? If yes then take a look [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi).

Comment: Yes it is.For compressing data.How can I use LZMA in Delphi,Can you explain me step by step..

Comment: There is I downloaded link:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/192/72669448.jpg/

Comment: You posted a link to a JPEG image. Is **that** what you downloaded?

Comment: my downloaded file includes them..

Comment: Please only use JPG for photorealistic images. Illustrations and screenshots look dreadful as JPG. Use PNG instead.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi

Comment: another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748504/lzma-for-delphi

Comment: If you had no idea what to do with it, why did you download it? What did you *intend* to do with it? If you don't know, how could anyone else? Voted to close: not a real question.

Comment: also a possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344976/lzma-or-7zip-in-delphi/4345821#4345821

Comment: LZMA <> "7-zip archive format", @daemon_x.

Comment: Man, it's a typo; I meaned 7z library. Anyway, if you're at it, how would you even download algorithm ?

Answer (score 5):

[Abbrevia 4](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia) supports decompressing LZMA streams in zip files using a statically linked version of the LZMA C SDK.  It includes pre-compiled copies of the .c files and links them using {$L abc.obj}, and is up to date (v9.20).  **AbLZMA.pas** has `LzDecode` and `LzEncode` functions that are compatible with the files the SDK generates.

Do note that that handles raw Lzma streams though, not the full .7z archive that 7-zip produces.  If you need that you're better off using the [Jedi Code Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/)'s **JclCompression** unit.

Comment: thank you..I download jedi code librarys.what will do now?

Comment: @Cenk: You need to use the TJclCompressArchive/TJclDecompressArchive classes.  Start with `GetArchiveFormats.FindCompressFormat` or `FindDecompressFormat` to get a specific subclass and then use the classes's functions to add/remove files.  There's some sample code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974736/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-jedis-jclcompression-to-create-a-7z-archive and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi

Comment: ok I m trying,thank you ı will turn back

Comment: I am sorry ı couldnt install them what can I install them?

Comment: @Cenk: The current JCL release is available for download at https://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/JCL%20Releases/JCL%202.2%20Build%203970/  It includes an Install.txt with installation instructions.  Just extract the zip and read through that.

Comment: I think I installed it,ı took a photo on delphi link:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/ca2ui.jpg/  now what will do?

Comment: @Cenk: JclCompression contains non-visual components.  You need to include it in your USES clause, open the .pas file in your editor, and see what you can do.  Take a look at the links in my first comment for example code.

Comment: I cant understand..Just I have a text file and I wanna compress it could you write an example code...

Comment: Hello I made it,but there is an error 'load 7z.dll' how can I solve this?

Comment: @Cenk: I think 7z.dll is part of the 7z922.exe package on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/  I don't use it myself though, so you might try the other packages there too.

Comment: See Jason Penny's answer here for a working sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi

Answer (score 2):

There is example code within the SDK (LZMAAlone) that is an example of using the decoder. You need to include most of the files under compression/{LZ,LZMA,RangeCoder}/ in your project to get it to work. The SDK doesn't generate a package that could be used as a compile-time/run-time package.

It works using TStreams, so you can use TMemoryStreams if you want to perform compression/decompression without using a file.

BTW the Delphi implementation is at the 4.42 revision, while the official SDK is at 9.20, which is a big difference!

Comment: also there is LZ LZMA Rangecoder in compress file

Comment: the RangeCoder is used for compressing items in the Dictionary IIRC. It's not generally used at the user level for compression/decompression